# how to open activity without clicking on fcm notification in android

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to open activity via fcm notification when app is closed and kill from background,ideal state. this time i need to open app. have any solution plz give m suggestion.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible with the lates Android versions. Maybe you should check this [docu](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts) on when an Activity from an App can be started when it's not in the foregrounf.